# Synchronise colours across multiple Highcharts graphs on one page

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a Highcharts spline graph on a web page, and would like to add a pie chart to a different place on the page that would display the total for each series on the spline graph.

I have added this as a new graph, however the colours do not match between the two graphs (i.e. series 1 is blue on the spline graph, but green on the pie) which is rather confusing for users.

Is it possible to link the series across the two graphs, or even just synchronise the colour within Highcharts?

I have tried iterating over all series in the spline graph and setting the colour of the matching segment in the pie chart to the same colour, but the colours do not change, even after running redraw()

Comment: When you create chart, why don't you set color for each pie slice/spline series ? Like this: `series: [{ type:'spline', color: 'red' }]` and `series: [{ type:'pie', data: [{ color: 'red'}]  }]`

Comment: ^agreed  or, use an associative array of colors paired to a series name, and reference the (e.g.) colors.seriesName wherever you need that color (saves work if you need to change the color array at any point).